# Tag merge / synonym request: [off-shore] → [offshore]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Could we merge [off-shore](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/off-shore) questions (10 total) into [offshore](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offshore) (3 total), and make them synonyms?

Side note. [distributed-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distributed-development) looks also worth considering as merge / synonym candidate for above.

Comment: Which do you want to be the master tag?

Comment: @ChrisF offshore - without hyphen - [Wikipedia seems to favor this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offshore "'Offshore' article")

Comment: Thought so, but just checking :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done - according to [offshore tag synonyms page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/offshore/synonyms),

> The following tags will be remapped to [offshore](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offshore)
>   [off-shore](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/off-shore)

---

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzEe0.jpg]

Answer (score 3):

[distributed-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distributed-development) seems like a tag for distributed systems development not developers themselves being distributed in general. This is a completely different tag. Though looking at the question it seems to be used in the latter sense so merging it may be good or just nuking it altogether.

Comment: good catch. From current (11) questions marked by this tag, it looks quite [ambiguous](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags "related discussion at MSO") - there are questions about _distributed anything_ - teams, VCS, computing